# Merge and delete rows of data

Tags: vba, excel

I need to write a macro to clean up an Excel document. I have most of the functions working now but I am having trouble merging two rows of data together. I need to first merge two rows of data, then delete the second one. This block of code is from the function I am having trouble with, I am deleting the correct rows fine but I would like to first merge together the row I want to delete with the row above so no data is lost; does anyone know if there's a quick command to merge whole rows together or do I have to do it cell by cell.

```
For RowCount = Selection.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1

    ' Delete rows that don't have text in col A
    If Selection.Cells(RowCount, 1).Text <> "" And IsNumeric(Selection.Cells(RowCount, 1).Value) Then
        'Is Number


    ElseIf Selection.Cells(RowCount, 1).Text = "Heading" Then
        'Its the Heading
    Else

        'Its not needed!
        '*********************************************************
        'CODE TO MERGE TWO ROWS SHOULD GO HERE********************
        '(MERGE ROWCOUNT-1 WITH ROWCOUNT AND DELETE ROWCOUNT)*****
        '*********************************************************

        Selection.Rows(RowCount).EntireRow.Delete
    End If

' Start next iteration of RowCount loop.
Next RowCount
```

Comment: Can you define what you mean by merge? If `RowCount -1` = A and 'RowCount`= B, you want 'RowCount -1' to be `A B` and then delete `RowCount`, for each Column in the Row, that is?

Comment: By merge I mean merge the values of the cells in each row. Your example is exactly what I would like to happen.

Comment: IS it just 1 column or is there a fixed number of columns or is it variable?

Comment: Whenever the code enters this if statement the row should be deleted, it will always be a variable amount. I search for any rows with an empty cell in collumn A and would like to delete that row, but first merge all of its cells values with the row above.

Comment: I got that part, I was just thinking how many columns in the row, but see my answer below. It should suffice for any amount of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do it cell by cell.

Replace:

```
'*********************************************************
'CODE TO MERGE TWO ROWS SHOULD GO HERE********************
'(MERGE ROWCOUNT-1 WITH ROWCOUNT AND DELETE ROWCOUNT)*****
'*********************************************************
```

With:

```
Dim ColumnCount As Integer, intCnt As Integer
ColumnCount = Selection.columns.count

For intCnt = 1 To ColumnCount

    Dim strRow As String, strPrevRow As String
    strRow = Selection.Cells(RowCount, intCnt).Text
    strPrevRow = Selection.Cells(RowCount, intCnt).offset(-1).Text

    Selection.Cells(RowCount, intCnt).offset(-1) = strRow & " " & strPrevRow

Next
```

Comment: Getting an error on strPrevRow = Selection.Cells(RowCount, ColumnCount).offset(-1).Text

Comment: Getting a runtime error, would that be if its deleting row 0, then it cant access row -1?

Comment: fixed my code to account for 1st error. Sorry about that. Tough to say on 2nd error, because there shouldn't be any row zero according to your code. WHat exactly is your selection? Is there more code that feeds this code?

Comment: hm now I am getting an error on Selection.Cells(RowCount, intCnt).Offset(-1).Text = strRow & " " & strPrevRow. I select all active cells because my macro mainly condenses a load of data into just a few collumns and rows that I would like to look at

Comment: edited again, get rid of `.Text` in that statement. Sorry, I didn't test this as I was too lazy to build a dataset for it!